# Unsetting array values (after casting an object to an array)

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting, json

Hello I am trying to unset an array element from this array

```
Array(
    [52] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => test
        [company] => sf
        [addr] => sdf
        [email] => sdf
        [phone] => sdf
        [comments] => sdf
        [qty] => 150
        [date] =>
        [brand] => Nike
        [quoteimg] => xx
        [enqimg] => xxx
        [product_name] => t5
        [key] => 52
        [action] => new_product
    )
)
```

i am using `unset($array['52']);`

but it doesn't work but an unknown reason.

```
function ajax_new_product(){
    $r=(array)json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['products']));

    if (isset($_POST['remove']))
        {   print_r($r);
            unset($r[$_POST['key']+0]);
            print_r($r);
        }   
    else 
        if(is_array($r) && !empty($r))
            if (isset ($_POST['key']))
                $r[$_POST['key']]=(array)$_POST;
            else        
                $r[]=(array)$_POST;     
        else 
            if (isset ($_POST['key']))
                $r[$_POST['key']]=(array)$_POST;
            else        
                $r[]=(array)$_POST;     
    setcookie('products',base64_encode(json_encode($r)),time()+60*60*24*30,"/");
}
```

this code :

```
if (isset($_POST['remove']))
    {   print_r($r);
        unset($r[$_POST['key']+0]);
        print_r($r);
    }
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [52] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test
            [company] => sf
            [addr] => sdf
            [email] => sdf
            [phone] => sdf
            [comments] => sdf
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7503-195x196.jpg
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7503-65x66.jpg
            [product_name] => t5
            [key] => 52
            [action] => new_product
        )

    [49] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => 
            [company] => 
            [addr] => 
            [email] => 
            [phone] => 
            [comments] => 
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ts21-164x196.png
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ts21-65x66.png
            [product_name] => t3
            [key] => 49
            [action] => new_product
        )

    [44] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => 
            [company] => 
            [addr] => 
            [email] => 
            [phone] => 
            [comments] => 
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7501-195x196.jpg
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7501-65x66.jpg
            [product_name] => Polo
            [key] => 44
            [action] => new_product
        )

)
Array
(
    [52] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test
            [company] => sf
            [addr] => sdf
            [email] => sdf
            [phone] => sdf
            [comments] => sdf
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7503-195x196.jpg
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7503-65x66.jpg
            [product_name] => t5
            [key] => 52
            [action] => new_product
        )

    [49] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => 
            [company] => 
            [addr] => 
            [email] => 
            [phone] => 
            [comments] => 
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ts21-164x196.png
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ts21-65x66.png
            [product_name] => t3
            [key] => 49
            [action] => new_product
        )

    [44] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => 
            [company] => 
            [addr] => 
            [email] => 
            [phone] => 
            [comments] => 
            [qty] => 150
            [date] => 
            [brand] => Nike
            [quoteimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7501-195x196.jpg
            [enqimg] => http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DESIGN_WONT_SAVE_THE_WORLD_TEE_AA_7501-65x66.jpg
            [product_name] => Polo
            [key] => 44
            [action] => new_product
        )

)
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/veryinfo/public_html/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/themes/custompolos/functions.php:32) in <b>/home/veryinfo/public_html/cristian/custompolos/wp/wp-content/themes/custompolos/functions.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
0
```

Comment: Don't use the surrounding quotes / apostrophes for numeric array indexes, i.e. $array[52] because 52 is a number, but $array['someKey'] because someKey is a string. Secondly, the array must be in a variable such as $array = array(52 => $object); Is the variable called $array? Make sure you run unset($variableName[52]); instead of just saying $array.

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: To juice it up a bit: `unset($array['52'+0]);`

Comment: sorry for messy code but i have tried a lot of things

Comment: @rid Thank you for your clarification, I am aware, but we are not concerned with the implementation details of PHP. The array is clearly indexed via numeric indexes, and so it is considered best practice to access it as such.

Comment: @XkiD to clarify your code for yourself and other who will read it, try to put real names for your variables, not just `r` or `kk`.

Comment: those are the real names

Comment: By real names I mean something more verbose

Comment: Is ajax_new_product even executed?

Comment: @XkiD, `var_dump($_POST['key'], $_POST['key']+0)`

Comment: because it is not an array.. it's std class so you can't use unset_array on it

Comment: @dualed, it is executed, see the output.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan, it is an array, see the output.

Comment: yes because it outputs my print_r's you can check here http://verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp/ , first add a click a product from the slider , add enquiry , and then click my quotes button from the top , click remove , and check xhr response.

Comment: i added  `if (isset($_POST['remove']))
  { print_r($r);
   unset($r[$_POST['key']+0]);
   print_r($r);
   var_dump($_POST['key'], $_POST['key']+0);
  }`

Comment: @XkiD, what did the `var_dump()` output?

Comment: you can check  verycreative.info/cristian/custompolos/wp , check xhr response when you click remove button from my quotes.

Comment: @rid string(2) "44"
int(44)

Comment: @XkiD, this is quite strange... `var_dump($_POST['key'], in_array($_POST['key'], array_keys($r)))`?

Comment: @rid `string(2) "44"
bool(true)`

Comment: @XkiD, `var_dump($_POST['key'], in_array($_POST['key'], array_keys($r))); unset($r[$_POST['key']]); var_dump($_POST['key'], in_array($_POST['key'], array_keys($r)));`?

Comment: string(2) "44"
bool(true)
string(2) "44"
bool(true)

Comment: try `json_decode($json, true)` instead of casting it to an array

Comment: @XkiD, `var_dump(gettype($r))`?

Comment: @XkiD, `$x = $r; $r = array(); foreach ($x as $k => $v) { if ($k != $_POST['key']) { $r[$k] = $v; } } var_dump(in_array($_POST['key'], array_keys($r)));`?

Comment: @dualed I need it as a array :(

Comment: @XkiD the 2nd parameter will make json_decode return an array. [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @XkiD, there seem to be some rather strange things that happen when you cast an object to an array... Can you try dualed's suggestion too, to see if that changes anything? (add a second `true` parameter to `json_decode()` and remove the cast to `array`) If it does, then this is because of the cast to array, which somehow seems to lock some properties of the object. If it doesn't, well, you can use the alternative of creating a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object seems to not really being completely converted to an array using the `(array)` cast. Unsetting is however only affected for numeric indexes.

To fix it, use the **second parameter** of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode), which makes it return a real array in the first place and everything should work fine.

### What happens?

From the discussion with rid, I offer the following compiled insight.

[The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states that converting an object to an array using `(array)` casting syntax makes numerical indexes inacessible, however a var_dump seems to imply something different:

```
$a = (array) json_decode('{"a": 123, "5": 234}');
var_dump($a);
// array(2) {
//   ["a"]=> int(123)
//   ["5"]=> int(234)
// }
```

The OPs problem came up when they tried to remove an numerically indexed entry from the array, in this case this would be trying to `unset($a[5]);` which does not affect the array at all. In fact, this code shows that nothing is there:

```
var_dump(isset($a['5'])); // bool(false)
var_dump($a['5']);        // NULL
$a["5"] = 1111;    
var_dump($a['5']);        // 1111
```

So, all is well? Well... almost, lets hazard another var_dump after that recent assignment

```
var_dump($a);
// array(3) {
//   ["a"]=>int(123)
//   ["5"]=>int(234)
//   [5]=>int(1111)
// }
```

Well this is suspicious, but we already made sure above that `$a[5]` returns the correct and new `1111`. And we can not access that *hidden five* anyway. Right? ... right?

```
foreach($a as $k=>$e) echo "$k -> $e\n";
// a -> 123
// 5 -> 234
// 5 -> 1111
```

Of course that is wrong. So wrong...

So I think, it is best **not to cast objects to arrays with current PHP versions**, use foreach instead to traverse them and create a completely new array this way. That is if you can not get a real array in the first place.

(Tested on PHP 5.4.8 Win)

Comment: Indeed. There's a section in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) talking about this: "If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible [...]"

Comment: @rid interestingly enough, the integer properties are accessible :) And thanks for the link, I was looking for that section...

Comment: @dualed, that's not the half of it... They don't seem to be either readable or writable, because you can't access them. Behold: `$a = (array) json_decode('{"a": 123, "5": 234}'); var_dump($a["5"]); $a["5"] = 1111; var_dump($a, $a["5"]);`! After 10 years of PHP, it never ceases to surprise me. Apparently there's something new to learn about PHP every day.

Comment: @rid I was just thinking 'do I really want to know?', though at least accessing `5` yields `1111`...

Comment: @dualed, it only does so after assigning it, because it's a new *kind* of `5`... (only in PHP)

Comment: @rid it is obviously *fiver* than the other five. If you want a laugh, try `foreach($a as $k=>$e) echo "$k -> $e\n";` after assigning 1111 to 5...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes:

`unset($array[52]);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `array_shift($array)`  which will eliminate the first index from your array